# How to run realm with android phone without crashing?

Tags: java, android, realm

1. So I just started using realm 5.8 and I cannot run with a mobile device it just crashes the app without any errors shown? what should I do?

Calling init and DefaultConf

```
 import android.app.Application;
 import io.realm.Realm;
 import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

 public class RealmApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
   }
```

And now the Activity file there we are trying to send input fields username and user_id to the database. I have on destroy getdefaultInstance() but nothing seems to work it just crashes? Do I need to somehow download the database to phone in order to make this work? Well, I have no idea more than I look less I think to understand.

```
     Realm realm;
 @Override
      protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.friends);
 username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    user_id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

     public void onClick(View view) {
    writeToDB(username.getText().toString().trim(), Integer.parseInt(user_id.getText().toString().trim()));
  }

 public void writeToDB(String username, int user_id) {
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
        Friend user = bgRealm.createObject(Friend.class);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setUser_id(user_id);
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // Transaction was a success.
        Log.v("Database","database success");
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
    }
});
}

   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
    }
```

Comment: You need to post the code. And If the app crashes you should see a stack trace. Please post that one as well

Comment: No the code works I think I need to download realm database to phone. But im not sure not that much information about the realm. Docs are good but didnt find this problem

Comment: In android studio, logcat tab set filter to `No filter`, level to `debug` and in the search field enter your package name. Start the app and watch logs. When app restart it clears log if you have set the filter to `Show only selected application`

Answer (score 0):

Well you should not be using xampp with your own settings reseted xampp and now I can run mysqli and realm in same project!